# org-mode in Emacs: eval chunks of code in asynchronous mode

Tags: asynchronous, eval, org-mode, halt

I am using org-mode to write reports including chunks of codes. When I want to generate the output (a PDF usually), org-mode executes all the commands in the file, which is fine. The problem however, is that during that executing, I cannot do anything else with emacs and I have to wait until all the commands to finish, which can take forever.

Is there a way to do the execution asynchronously, or at least, stop the execution once it's started?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should use this to avoid executing those blocks.

```
(setq org-export-babel-evaluate nil)
```

It doesn't make sense to run them asynchronously during export, because then the output won't be available for the report. Alternatively, you could try doing an asynchronous export. After you type C-c C-e then type C-a to turn async export on. That should do the export in another process, and not block your current one.

Comment: thanks, that helps! Would you know a similar trick to execute single blocks of codes asynchronously?

Comment: I did this for Python here http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/11/20/Asynchronously-running-python-blocks-in-org-mode/. I have adapted it for shell commands but it isn't out anywhere as I haven't tested it much.